# How Do I Configure RealityKit/Reality Composer Pro Entities to Output Spatial Audio in visionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I'm working on my first visionOS application, and I'd like to get at least some form of spatial audio working. The plan is to have an immersive space where I have two assets placed as follows:

[image: This is my current Reality Composer Pro Configuration]

I have already created the immersive space

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

    struct ImmersiveView: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            RealityView { content in
                // Add the initial RealityKit content
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                    content.add(scene)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    #Preview {
        ImmersiveView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
```

which is working fine, and I have added an audio source component with an audio reference to each entity in reality composer. Now, my question is, how do I implement this in code? I've been doing a bit of research into how spatial audio works and I haven't found much. I did find an example on Apple's developer site which describes attaching spatial sound to a satellite orbiting Earth (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10080/?time=937). However, I found the code snippet on implementing spatial audio wasn't very helpful as it doesn't really get in to how Entities work inside of swift.

```
    // Create an empty entity to act as an audio source.
let audioSource = Entity()

// Configure the audio source to project sound out in a tight beam.
audioSource.spatialAudio = SpatialAudioComponent(directivity: .beam(focus: 0.75))

// Change the orientation of the audio source (rotate 180º around the Y axis).
audioSource.orientation = .init(angle: .pi, axis: [0, 1, 0])

// Add the audio source to a parent entity, and play a looping sound on it.
if let audio = try? await AudioFileResource(named: "SatelliteLoop",
                                            configuration: .init(shouldLoop: true)) {
    satellite.addChild(audioSource)
    audioSource.playAudio(audio)
}
```

This is the code used to play spatial audio from a satellite entity. What's frustrating is that other resources I've found all seem to have different ways to implement spatial audio. Like Apple's "Destination Video" which uses an `AVAudioSessionSpatialExperience` and an `AVAudioSession` which is entirely different from the satellite project. I have also consulted Apple's developer documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technologies), but there's just so much there I'm not really sure what to look for.

If anyone has any helpful resources for getting started with spatial audio (and even RealityKit) that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add a AudioEmitter to the Reality Composer Pro scene (.usda) and access that in the code like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
   
   private var playbackController: AudioPlaybackController?
   
   var body: some View {
      RealityView { content in
         // Add the initial RealityKit content
         if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
            //Accessing ambient emitter
            let audioEntity = scene.findEntity(named: "AmbientEmitter")
            // Add the audio source to a parent entity, and play a looping sound on it.
            //example from Apple code to find the audio file res
            if let audio = try? await AudioFileResource(named: "SatelliteLoop",
                                                        configuration: .init(shouldLoop: true)) {
               playbackController = audioEntity?.prepareAudio(resource)
               playbackController?.play()
            }
            content.add(scene)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

this should enable the audio with reality composer pro in visionOS.